# Serverless Lambda SQS access denied error

Tags: amazon-sqs, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a node application running through `serverless-framework`.

The application writes messages to the SQS and code is

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const config = require('../../configs/constants').config;

const sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05'});

module.exports.sendMessage = (service, message) => {
    const params = {
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message),
        QueueUrl: config.SQS_QUEUE_URL_ANALYTICS
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sqs.sendMessage(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error creating SQS Message: ', err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                console.log('SQS Message created successfully: ', data);
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

The permission given to the user is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:ListQueues",
                "sqs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:881210447458:Staging-Analytics-Log-Data-Process"
        }
    ]
}
```

When the lambda function is executed, it gives an error

```
ERROR Error creating SQS Message: { AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.
```

What other credentials are required for SQS to run?

Answer (score 3):

**Insert this permission under your `provider:` tab in serverless.yml:**

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - sqs:SendMessage
  Resource: <your swq ARN that starts with (arn:aws:sqs:)>
```

Answer (score 2):

To send message from AWS Lambda to SQS, you **need IM role attached to your Lambda** to send messages to SQS. Because in AWS, you need permission for accessing other services resources:

1. Create IM ROLE with permission for SQS or Required Access
2. Assign Created IM Role while creating Lambda function at start
3. See Permission assigned permission for your lambda at Permission tab

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the wildcard is missing your permissions, but from the code you posted you should only need the permissions to send message.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:SendMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:881210447458:Staging-Analytics-Log-Data-Process"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Had the same configuration earlier but replaced after getting error to allow wildcard permission in hope that may be some permission is missing but still getting the error.

Comment: Can you confirm the name of the queue? Its case sensitive. Have several lambdas with these policies

Comment: Also something that I noticed did you cut queue name from the error message? Looks like it is something missing there